# Can I specify a "chunk size" for git svn fetch?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm cloning an SVN repo with git and everything seems to be working fine. The very last revision I need to download contains a ~220MB zip file.

I know this isn't an issue for git, however the school's server I'm downloading it from hangs up half way through the file which invalidates the entire index requiring that it re-download the revision again.

Is there a way to tell git-svn fetch to get an index in multiple chunks of a particular chunk-size or to retain the partial index if the server hangs up?

Spec info:
Win7 with Cygwin 1.7.9-1
git & git-svn 1.7.4-1

Comment: This sounds like a sufficiently rare case that I don't think it's implemented. But as it's an open-source project with very responsive developers, I suggest you ask on `git@vger.kernel.org` mailing list. You don't have to be subscribed—like in other kernel lists, the custom there is to keep people involved in each thread on CC (i.e. use "reply to all" when replying to list posts).

Comment: Thanks! I just popped them a message. I'll report back if there's anything else.

Comment: I wonder if you could do some clever hack where you download the file directly using svn itself, then commit it to git, but make it look like it came from git-svn, by setting the author, committer, and username to look the way git-svn would have made them look. Then when you do `git svn fetch` or whatever, it will just go "Oh okay, we've already got that commit."

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to leave out the big zip file from your repository, you could try the following:

Make two clones, one before the over-sized commit, and one for afterwards.  Say the big commit was committed in revision 36, it would be something like:

git svn clone -r1:35 url first-clone
git svn clone -r36:HEAD url second-clone

Now fetch the second repo into the first repo, and tie the history together using *grafts*. I've made a screencast with an example of grafting like this here:

http://blog.tfnico.com/2010/10/gitsvn-6-grafting-together-svn-history.html